# How should i get result used stream in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

here a string[]

```
String[] strings = {"3", "1", "4", "3", "2"};
```

i want to change this to a number then sort and cumulative operations

1. change number

```
int[] ints = {3, 1, 4, 3, 2};
```

2. sort

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
```

3. cumulative operations

```
1           =    1
1+2         =    3
1+2+3       =    6 
1+2+3+3     =    9
1+2+3+3+4   =   13

result      =   1+3+6+9+13  = 32
```

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4};

int result = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            sum += ints[j];
        }
    result += sum;
}
```

```
result = 32
```

finally, i want to change this code to stream.

i have tried to:

```
String[] strings = {"3", "1", "4", "3", "2"};
            
int asInt = stream(strings)
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .sorted()
                .reduce(Integer::sum)
                .getAsInt();
```

```
asInt = 13
```

what should I do to get the result i want?

Comment: to simply convert, try using `IntStream.range...`  for both your loops.

Comment: The only thing you should do is to use the right operation. What does `Integer::sum` is to sum elements of a stream. As you define your operation, it requires to break functional benefits of Stream (access the full stream to get the result). Possibly it can be sorted in a way to make it Stream-able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] strings = {"3", "1", "4", "3", "2"};
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

Arrays.stream(strings)
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
      .sorted()
      .map(ai::addAndGet).sum();  // returns 32
```

Comment: No need for a `reduce` just use `sum()` after `map(ai::addAndGet)`

Comment: @Eritrean for `AtomicInteger`, you will need `reduce()`: `sum()` won't work unless another conversion is done before

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero no. you could use `map(ai::addAndGet).sum()` because at that point the stream is an `IntStream` so you could use `sum()`

Comment: Fixed to add comments from @GauthamM

Answer (score 1):

There's almost certainly a better approach, but as a quick solution until someone gives a better one:

```java
final int[] index = {strings.length};
final int result = Arrays.stream(strings)
                         .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                         .sorted()
                         .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + (index[0]-- * b));
```

The idea here being that your desired number counts the first number 5 times, the second one 4 times, the third one 3 times, etc.

Using a `final int[]` as basically a variable that can be used in the stream (must be `final`).  `index[0]--` on each step to ensure the next one is multiplied by less.

Comment: I learned a lot from your ideas. Thank you so much. 

Answer (score 1):

A declartive, straightforward solution:

1. `Map` and `sort` the array.
2. Create an `IntStream` of 1 to array's length and `sum` the first i elements `sum` each time.

Code:

```
String[] strings = {"3", "1", "4", "3", "2"};

int[] ints = Arrays.stream(strings)
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .sorted()
        .toArray();

int cumulativeSum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, ints.length)
        .map(i -> Arrays.stream(ints)
                .limit(i)
                .sum())
        .sum();
```

Output:

```
32
```